# How to load a tabbar controller xib using navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to ios, I had a problem with tabbar controller. I am using two tab bar controller in my project.One is loaded at app lunch and it is working good.I want to load another at didselect row.How to do this. I have done many experiments but nothing works.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Your question title and you question description seems to tell different things. What do you actually want to do? What is your parent viewcontroller? NavigationController or Tabbarcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) hidetabbar {
    [UIView  animateWithDuration:0.5
                      animations:^{
                          for(UIView *view in tabBarController.view.subviews)
                          {
                              if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
                              {
                                  if (hiddenTabBar) {
                                      [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
                                  } else {
                                      [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
                                  }
                              } else {
                                  if (hiddenTabBar) {
                                      [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
                                  } else {
                                      [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }];
    hiddenTabBar = !hiddenTabBar;
}   


when u r clicking on the table view did select row hide the tabbar in the viewcontroller that u r sending

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    [((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]) hidetabbar];
}








-(void)tabBarControllerView
{
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    //Add some tabs to the controller...

    //----First tab----//
    //-----second Tab   -----//

    //------3rd tab--//

    //-----4th tab bar--------//

    //-----5th tab bar--------//

    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];



    [navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
    tabBarController.tabBar.tag=100;

    tabBarController.view.hidden = NO;
}


- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarControllers didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController  
{
    if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
    }
    else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 1)
    {

    }
    else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 2)
    {


    }
    else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 3)
    {
    }
    else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 4)
    {

    }
}
```

hide main tab bar in that view controller where  u r doing the did select table and add another tab bar..
  try some thing like this it may help u

Comment: Hi,My parent view controller is tabbar controller.In didselect row i want to load a new tabbar controller. How to do it

Comment: give a tag value to u r parent view tab bar controller and in did select row u will be directed to another view controller in that check the tabcontroller view object and with the help of the tag value remove the tab bar from that view cotroller and add  u r new tab bar controller in that class

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Code in didSelect event

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    NSArray*tabBarimageArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"firstTabImage.png",@"secondTabImage.png", nil];




    YourFirstTabRootViewController *firstVc = [[YourFirstTabRootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourFirstTabRootViewController" bundle:nil];




    UINavigationController *firstNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstVc];


    YourSecondTabRootViewController *secondVc = [[YourSecondTabRootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourFirstTabRootViewController" bundle:nil];




    UINavigationController *secondNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondVc];


    NSArray *VCs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstNavigationController,secondNavigationController nil];
    NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      NSLocalizedString(@"Tab1", @""), 
                      NSLocalizedString(@"Tab2", @""),

                      nil];

    NSMutableArray *tabBarViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[VCs count]];
    NSInteger index = 0;


    for (id controller in VCs) {




        UINavigationController * navController = controller ;
                // THIS SETS UP THE TAB BAR ITEMS/IMAGES AND SET THE TAG FOR TABBAR_ITEM_TAGS
                NSString *tabName = [names objectAtIndex:index];
                UIImage *tabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[tabBarimageArray objectAtIndex:index]]];
                navController.title = tabName;
                UITabBarItem *tempTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:tabName 
                                                                      image:tabImage 
                                                                        tag:index];
                navController.tabBarItem = tempTab;

                [tabBarViewControllers addObject:navController];
        index ++;

        }





    [ tabBarController setViewControllers:tabBarViewControllers];

    [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```